# Exponential Generating Function for certain trees

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees

I am trying to find the exponential generating function for rooted labeled plane trees with each vertex in the tree having an even number of children.

I am hoping to do this with Lagrange inversion but I have not been successful. I have seen it demonstrated for rooted labeled plane trees with no restrictions, but I am not sure how to account for this new condition requiring even numbers of children. Can someone show how I might do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small hint:

The normal egf equation is
$$
T(x)=x\Big(1+T(x)+T(x)^2/2!+T(x)^3/3!+\dots\Big)=x\exp T(x)
$$
The $1$ accounts for the tree with only the root vertex, the $T(x)$ for trees where the root has one child, and in general $T(x)^k/k!$ accounts for trees where the root has $k$ children. How should you modify this if you only want to count trees where the root has an even number of children, instead of any $k$?

Comment: I see. That definitely helps. So would it be correct to say that the function I am interested in satisfies: T(x)=x(1+T(x)^2/2!+T(x)^4/4!...) then?

Comment: Yep! And there is a closed form for that infinite summation.